# Solr facet count for specific words

Tags: solr, faceted-search, facet

I am trying to find the facet count for a particular field in my Solr Implementation.

I was wondering if there is a way to get facet counts for only a few specific words in that field?

For example,

field name = product

values can be camera <10> , tv <20> , DVD <20> , CD <30>

Now is it possible to get the facet counts of only tv and DVD?

I tried using facet.prefix, but it does not work for multiple values.

--Jay

Comment: why not just filter them client-side?

Comment: Thats what I am doing as of now. But I think for my application it would be better if I can get facet counts of specific words as result. (instead of taking the entire facet count result set and selecting specific ones from it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr support faceting by arbitrary queries as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_%3a_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting).

So, in your case you could get facet counts for only tv and DVD by the following query:
[http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.query=product:tv&facet.query=product:DVD](http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=%2a%3a%2a&facet=true&facet.query=product%3atv&facet.query=product%3aDVD)

Comment: Thank you so much. :) . Perfect for my application.